# Passing a file containing a list of files/directories to Doxygen INPUT tag

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to passing a file containing a list of files/directories to Doxygen INPUT tag. 
In case the sentence above does not describe my intention clearly, consider an example where I would like to include these files and directories for the Doxygen to scan and generate some documentation:
./file_1.c
./file_1.h
./file_2.c
./dir_1
./dir_2/file_20.c
./dir_3/file_31.c ... etc.

If only those items I want to include, I could simply append it to the INPUT tag, and make it look like this:

```
INPUT = ./file_1.c \
        ./file_1.h \
        ./file_2.c \
        ./dir_1    \
        ./dir_2/file_20.c \
        ./dir_3/file_31.c
```

However if the list grows, and if the files are not necessarily confined to a certain directory, it would be nice to put that list on a separate file, let's call it doxyInput.lst, and 'pass' it to Doxygen.

I tried it. I put the list above to the doxyInput.lst and just set the INPUT tag in my Doxy config file to this:

```
INPUT = doxyInput.lst
```

But that does not work.

Is what I'm trying to do here supported by Doxygen?

I tried looking it up on the Internet, but I guess I don't know the proper search term, so I didn't find what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add a list with file names directly to e.g. `INPUT` but there are some possibilities like:

- you don't have to list all files individually, but you can use directories in `INPUT` as well and use `FILE_PATTERNS` to select only relevant file extensions. Use `RECURSIVE` to go into sub directories and use `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS` to exclude file(patterns).
- place all the file names in a separate file (don't forget the backslash at the 
  end!) and use `@INCLUDE` in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile).